# Print the rank of runner according to finishing their thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Runner class which extends Thread. In main class, I have bunch of objects of Runner class which start race at the same time. I want to print the rank of each runner based on the time taken to finish their thread.

```
private void raceStart() throws InterruptedException
{
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Thread.sleep((long) (reaction * 1000));
    int track = 100;
    int playerLocation = 0;
    Random randomDelay = new Random();
    double delay = 90 + randomDelay.nextInt(16);
    for(int i = 0; i <= track; i++)
    {
        if(playerLocation == track)
        {
            long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double totalTime = (double)(finish - start) / 1000;
            System.out.format("%d %d %d %-12s %-12s %-25s %.3f %.3f%n" , rank, lane, bib, country, lastName, firstName, reaction, totalTime);
        }
        playerLocation++;
        Thread.sleep((long) delay);
    }
}
```

In my main class,

```
private void run()
{
    Runner usainBolt = new Runner(1, 6, 2612, "JAM", "Bolt", "Usain", 0.155);
    Runner justinGatlin = new Runner(2, 4, 3069, "USA", "GATLIN", "Justin", 0.152);
    Runner andreDeGrasse = new Runner(3, 7, 2196, "CAN", "DE GRASSE", "Andre", 0.141);
    Runner yohanBlake = new Runner(4, 9, 2611, "JAM", "BLAKE", "Yohan", 0.145);
    Runner akaniSimbine = new Runner(5, 3, 2909, "RSA", "SIMBINE", "Akani", 0.128);
    Runner benYoussefMeite = new Runner(6, 8, 2245, "CIV", "MEITE", "Ben Youssef", 0.156);
    Runner jimmyVicaut = new Runner(7, 5, 2434, "FRA", "VICAUT", "Jimmy", 0.140);
    Runner trayvonBromell = new Runner(8, 2, 3054, "USA", "BROMWELL", "Trayvon", 0.135);
    
    
    List<Runner> runners = Arrays.asList(usainBolt, justinGatlin, andreDeGrasse, 
            yohanBlake, akaniSimbine, benYoussefMeite, jimmyVicaut, trayvonBromell);
                    
    for (Runner r : runners)
    {
        
        r.start();
        
    }
```

I also want to print the total time taken by the whole program in the end.
I tried

```
 long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
 run(0);
 long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
 double totalTime = (double)(finish - start) / 1000;
 System.out.println("totalTime");
```

But it always prints 0 or 1 before displaying the results.

Comment: So one possibility is to have the runner callback an observer when it finishes, the problem with this is it would probably need to be synchronised and this could generate a race condition.  So each runner would probably also need to keep a time value which indicates the time it finished, so you can get a better idea of when a runner actually finished

Comment: I got the idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since a lot of this is time recording based, I'd recommend creating a simple StopWatch class that each runner can hold on to and record their individual times.

```
    public class StopWatch {
        private long startTime = -1;
        private long stopTime = -1;
        private long currentTime = 0;
        private boolean isRunning = false;
        public void start(){
            isRunning = true;
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }

        public void stop(){
            stopTime = System.nanoTime();
        }

        public long getCurrentTime(){
            if (startTime != -1 && stopTime == -1){
                currentTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            }else if (startTime != -1 && stopTime != -1){
                currentTime = stopTime - startTime;
            }
            return currentTime;
        }

        public boolean isRunning(){
            if(startTime != -1 && stopTime == -1){
                isRunning = true;
            }
            return isRunning;
        }

        public void reset(){
            startTime = -1;
            stopTime = -1;
            currentTime = 0;
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what your Runner class looks like but I've made just a simple one that determines speed randomly and adds a random amount every second to each runner(you can create your own method in Runner to determine how quick each runner is). I would also implement comparable to runner so that you can sort them based on distance traveled and finally overide toString() method in Runner to print the relevant information that will be used for the leaderboard later.

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    
    public class Runner extends Thread implements Comparable {
    
        boolean hasFinished = false;
        int distanceTraveled = 0;
        StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();
        Random speed = new Random();
        int raceDistanceMeters = 100;
        private String nameF;
        private String nameL;
    
    
        public Runner(String nameL, String nameF) {
            this.nameF = nameF;
            this.nameL = nameL;
        }
    
        public void run() {
            timer.start();
            while(hasFinished == false){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    distanceTraveled = distanceTraveled + speed.nextInt(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (distanceTraveled >= raceDistanceMeters){
                    hasFinished = true;
                    distanceTraveled = raceDistanceMeters;
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object compareRunner) {
            int compareDistanceTraveled = ((Runner)compareRunner).distanceTraveled;
            return compareDistanceTraveled-this.distanceTraveled;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.nameF + " " + this.nameL + " " + "Distance: " + distanceTraveled + " Time: " + (Double.valueOf(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(timer.getCurrentTime())))/1000;
        }
    }
```

You can now use ArrayLists of type Runner with Collections.sort and also print each of the runners after sorting.

A Race class makes sense as it will allow some house keeping items related to that specific race such as the runners competing along with printing a leaderboard.

```
    public class Race {
        ArrayList<Runner> runners = new ArrayList<>();
    
        public void addRunner(Runner runner){
            runners.add(runner);
        }
    
        public void start(){
            runners.forEach(runner -> runner.start());
        }
    
        public void printLeaderboard(){
            Collections.sort(runners);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
            runners.forEach(runner -> System.out.println(runner.toString()));
        }
    
        public boolean isRaceOver() {
            int count = 0;
            for (Runner runner : runners) {
                if (runner.hasFinished == true){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == runners.size()){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So an example of what Main() would look like.

```
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.start();
            ArrayList<Runner> runners = new ArrayList<>();
            runners.add(new Runner("Bolt", "Usain"));
            runners.add(new Runner("GATLIN", "Justin"));
            runners.add(new Runner("DE GRASSE", "Andre"));
            runners.add(new Runner("BLAKE", "Yohan"));
            runners.add(new Runner("SIMBINE", "Akani"));
            runners.add(new Runner("MEITE", "Ben Youssef"));
            runners.add(new Runner("VICAUT", "Jimmy"));
            runners.add(new Runner("BROMWELL", "Trayvon"));
    
            Race race1 = new Race();
            runners.forEach(runner -> race1.addRunner(runner));
            race1.start();
            while (!race1.isRaceOver()){
                Thread.sleep(500);
                race1.printLeaderboard();
            }
            System.out.println("Total Run time: " + (Double.valueOf(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(stopWatch.getCurrentTime())))/1000);
        }
    }
```